# PHP tar returning path back to root

Tags: php, system, tar

I'm running the following command to create a backup tarball of a file or folder:

```
system("tar -pczf /home/var/www/temp /home/var/www/folder/to/backup");
```

It works great, but when I extract I get the path all the way back to the root of the server (/home/var/www/folder/to/backup).

I'm curious if there's a command or flag which will allow me to create the tarball so it only contains the '/folder/to/backup' part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use relative paths :

```
system("tar -pczf /home/var/www/temp folder/to/backup");
```

Or if your backup directory is on a lower-level one :

```
system("tar -pczf /home/var/www/temp ../../folder/to/backup");
```

Some [doc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29) about relative/absolute paths.

Comment: Thanks, I tried rel paths and it didn't work, but I think I may have missed a level.

Comment: There is a useful function, [realpath()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php), to clarify your relative paths.